# The number of ways of reading an xml file from another server in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, apache

I am trying to read an XML-file from another server. However the the company that's hosting me seems to have turned of the file_get_contents function from retrieving files for files from other servers (and their support is not very bright and it takes forever for them to answer). So I need a work around in some way.

This is my current code

```
 $url =  urldecode( $object_list_url );
 $xmlstr = file_get_contents ( $url );
 $obj = new SimpleXMLElement ( $xmlstr, LIBXML_NOCDATA );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [cURL](http://www.php.net/curl) (if that's not been disabled).
Something like this:

```
$c = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$xmlstr = curl_exec($c);
```

Comment: Apparently allow_url_fopen doesn't cover cURL so this might be your best bet.

Comment: I would recommend cURL too - it's much more reliable and secure than allow_url_fopen.

Comment: Hmm good answer tried some of the stuff in the link I seem to be getting a "CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when in safe_mode or an open_basedir"-warning/error, other than that it seems I get a "Object moved to here"-message. Is this fixable?

Comment: Got it working. The problem was the location header of the file I was requesting was pointing to another file, setting the CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION didn't work because of security. So what I did was taking the URL of the file pointed at by the header and adding it to cURL. Ugly solution but it works.

Answer (score 0):

The ini var you're referring to is `allow_url_fopen`. To check, run this script:

```
var_dump(ini_get('allow_url_fopen'));
```

Ask your host to turn that ini value on (if it's disabled - it's on by default).

You should not be able to access any remote url without that ini setting on.

Also an idea if they won't could be to try [`copy`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php)ing the file to your server. I expect all filesystem functions will be covered by that ini setting but it's always worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Can you execute the following script and provide the information as a comment?

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Comment: Won't fit in the 300 characters...but cURL is turned on.